# Copy a Column Format based on header row Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to replicate the format of the top row of an excel sheet to selected cells down each selected column.

- I cannot use conditional formatting or any formula in the destination cells, because they contain data and a different conditional formatting formula already.
- The Entire Column is grouped. Over time, i may change the grouping level and dont want to re-format the entire sheet... the top row background color has a conditional formatting applied.. using the following formula.

  ```
  Function OutlineLev(inp As Integer) As Integer
  OutlineLev = Columns(inp).OutlineLevel
  End Function
  ```

So in the example, cell background on row 1  group level 1 is orange,  level 2 is blue and L3 is green. (conditional format rule  `=OutlineLev(CELL("col",D1))=3` )

- You can see that row 2 (yellow cells) have no content. Originally i thought i would hava a formula in that cell, to copy the format of the top row down to the other rows within each column...

Essentially. i am looking for a macro/function/formula that will somehow copy the background of the top row (say Cell D1 in example). down to the rest of the column (Range (D3:D9 in example).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this code

```
Sub ApplyFormatting()
    CopyFormat Range("A3:A10"), Range("A1")
    CopyFormat Range("B3:B10"), Range("B1")
    CopyFormat Range("C3:C10"), Range("C1")
    CopyFormat Range("D3:D10"), Range("D1")
End Sub

Sub CopyFormat(dest As Range, copyfrom As Range)
    dest.Interior.Color = copyfrom.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

to the code area of your worksheet, you have a simple tool that almost does what you want. The only thing is that you have to call the `ApplyFormatting` subroutine somewhere. For example, if the colors of the first row depends on values of some cells somewhere **on the same worksheet**, you could use the Worksheet_Change event of that sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ApplyFormatting
End Sub
```

Note that this event is not directly triggered by a change of a background color of some cell, only when a cell **value** changes. That might proably be enough in your case, but since you forgot to tell us how your first row is formatted exactly, I can only guess.

EDIT: to your comment: there is no need to hardcode the range specification, the above was just an example to demonstrate how to copy formats.

A solution which applies this to the whole sheet will look like this:

```
Sub ApplyFormatting()
    Dim maxRow As Long, maxCol As Long, col As Long
    maxRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    maxCol = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    For col = 1 To maxCol
        CopyFormat Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(maxRow, col)), Cells(1, col)
    Next
End Sub
```

You may have to restrict/adapt this to the rows/columns in your actual sheet, but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for this response, this worked!, however i will apply this to many records and do not want to hard-code the cell ranges into the function. the data is too dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for this!... just what i am looking for!... the only problem is, that on my worksheet this does not work, (i think it has something to do with the fact that the referenced cells are based on a formula to determine their interior color)... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the format for a whole column will result in a smaller filesize.  It seems like a better approach to set the format for a whole column, and then override the format for row #2 with a conditional formatting rule.  This way you can avoid VBA altogether, and your formatting rules apply to whole columns or the whole sheet, which is optimal.

Select the entire sheet and create a conditional formatting rule that uses the formula `=row()=2` and set the `fill` to `black`.

Then you can select an entire column and apply any formatting the *whole column* that you want.  The conditional formula is applied last so the black row #2 remains.

If you only want the background to be set for the whole column, then just set that, and change the font color for just the cells on row #1...

In the end it is the same amount of work, because you have to set the formatting for cells and run the macro, or set the settings for the column and change the font color of the top cell...

FYI - If you only want to make the black bar on row #2 extend the width of the used columns (instead of the width of the entire sheet), then select cell A1 before selecting the whole sheet and use the formula `=and(row()=2,a$1<>"")` for the conditional formula.

Comment: i intend that the column formats will be dynamic, so i dont want to set the format manually. the reason for this is that cell A2 will change format based on a separate formula ( which is linked to the group level of the column. so this will not work *(unless i have not understood correctly)

Comment: How is the background being set that you want to copy to the rest of the column?  Your illustration and your question don't mention that, or anything about 'group level'.  Can you clarify?  If 'group level' is row #1, how does row #1's format get set so it can be copied?